# Would Truesight detect a Skulk?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, invisibility, special-senses

This [Skulk's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/skulk) Special Trait lists 3 conditions that can see through their invisibility (mirrors, special candles and preteens), but it doesn't list Truesight as one of the means, and further is called *Fallible Invisibility.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Yes, it would.

The description of the [skulk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/skulk)'s Fallible Invisibility trait says (*Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*, p. 227):

> The skulk is invisible. This invisibility can be circumvented by three
> things:
>
> - The skulk appears as a drab, smooth-skinned humanoid if its
>   reflection can be seen in a mirror or on another surface.
> - The skulk appears as a dim, translucent form in the light of a candle
>   made of fat rendered from a corpse whose identity is unknown.
> - Humanoid children, aged 10 and under, can see through this
>   invisibility.

The Skulk's invisibility can be circumvented by those means, which means that the invisibility fails to be effective in such conditions. However, characters with truesight can see invisible targets, so they do not need to circumvent it, as they could already see it normally.

The description of [Truesight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Truesight) says (emphasis mine):

> A monster with truesight can, out to a specific range, see in normal
> and magical darkness, **see invisible creatures and objects**,
> automatically detect visual illusions and succeed on saving throws
> against them, and perceive the original form of a shapechanger or a
> creature that is transformed by magic. Furthermore, the monster can
> see into the Ethereal Plane within the same range.

Comment: You might want to note that the description for the skulk doesn't say those are the only means of circumventing their invisibility.

Comment: @AllanMills What do you mean? Care to explain? The description even enumerates the possibilities... Why would it do that if there were other ways (at least not in the description)?

If you're talking about these not being the only way to see invisibility, i would say that the term "circumvent" refers to "bypass", or to "overcome" an obstacle. So, if invisibility is an issue, these are the ways it could be circumvented. If you can see invisible creatures already, you have no need to bypass their invisibility, as it does not represent an obstacle to you.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if there are instances of Skulks in D&D story books which would provide more information as to the flavor of this creature. ...I find it odd that such specific conditions to circumvent the Skulks' invisibility would be ignored by having truesight. BUT on the other hand, the Skulks do only have CR of 1/2 and the *True Seeing* spell which can grant truesight is a 6th level spell, so I think you are right. :)

Comment: @AlanRégis I meant that the description only states some special, extra ways to bypass the invisibility of the skulk on top of the other means of overcoming invisibility like faerie fire etc.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, but the reason I asked, is that in general spells/abilities do only what they say they do. Since the Skulks ability specifies that there are three ways to circumvent it, that suggests the possibility that no other means would do so.